# How to divide an array on sub arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, signals

I wrote some code, at first I've created a sin wave with increasing frequency and store it in txt file (s). I divided it and extract one second only, I applied window on signal (s_) and calculate the fft.

Now I want to do for loop, to divide my signal at every second and calculate the fft.

how can i do this please?

thanks in advance,

```
s = pd.read_csv('sinwave.out')
time = pd.read_csv('time.out')
f_s = 2000
fig, figure4 = plt.subplots()
figure4.plot(time, s)
s_=s.iloc[0:2000,0] 
time_=time.iloc[0:2000,0]
win = np.kaiser(len(s_), 1)
s_win = s_ * win
fig, figure5 = plt.subplots()
figure5.plot(time_, s_win)
figure5.set_xlim(0, 1)
S_ = fftpack.rfft(s_win)
freqs_ = fftpack.rfftfreq(len(s_win)) * f_s
fig, figure6 = plt.subplots()
figure6.plot(freqs_, abs(S_))
figure6.set_xlim(0, 60)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(abs(S_), height=600, )
indexes = peaks/2
print(indexes)
```

Comment: use `numpy.split` to split array/signal: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html

Comment: Thank you Masoud, I will try this

Comment: Hi Masoud, I tried numpy.split but i got an error "ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division"  because i want to divide it into 10 sub arrays but my signal have 19999 points.

Comment: simply, append a value to the end of array before splitting